# Customizing navigation menu in Big Cartel with custom pages

Tags: bigcartel

I'm using the Luna Theme with Big Cartel, site here: http://shop.katekoeppel.com

I'd like all my custom pages to appear in the navigation menu at the top of the page (right now they only show up on the bottom menu). The pages I'd like to add are: Press, Shipping + Policies and Retailers. Ideally I'd like both menus to mirror each other.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the Luna theme only lists a couple custom pages up top -- but you can change this behavior by just modifying a bit of code. Head to Customize Design > Advanced > Layout and find this code:

```
<nav id="main_nav">
  <ul>
    <li {% if page.full_url contains '/products' or page.full_url contains '/product/' or page.full_url contains '/category/' or page.full_url contains '/artist/' %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="/products">Products</a></li>{% for page in pages.all limit:2 %}<li {% if page.full_url contains page.url %}class="selected"{% endif %}>{{ page | link_to }}</li>{% endfor %}<li {% if page.full_url contains '/contact' %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li><li {% if page.full_url contains '/cart' %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="/cart">Cart</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Remove the `limit:2` in that block of code to have all your pages listed (or change the 2 to any number of your choice) and you're all set.